# Restoring session objects after migration to Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security

After migration from Spring Security 4.0.x to Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE i cannot restore `SecurityContext` from session because of different `serialVersionUID`.

```
public class SecurityContextImpl implements SecurityContext {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;
...
}
```

exception:

```
Exception while loading session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 400, local class serialVersionUID = 410
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:58)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.DatastoreSessionStore.createSessionFromEntity(DatastoreSessionStore.java:58)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.DatastoreSessionStore.getSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:85)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.loadSession(SessionManager.java:330)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:303)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.getHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:237)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.setRequestedId(SessionHandler.java:246)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 400, local class serialVersionUID = 410
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1907)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1462)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:417)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1182)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1462)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:417)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:56)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: I doubt it was a Spring update but rather a Spring Security update... And indeed you cannot deserialize those as intended. Clear the stored sessions (remove them).

Comment: Does anyone know how I can do this on GAE?

Comment: clear table `_ah_sessions`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot restore those sessions given the Spring security update, as suggested by M. Deinum.  They must be cleared to begin using sessions properly again.  You can do this, as Igor suggested, by deleting _ah_SESSION entities in the Datastore.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. For my case, it was due to the XML schema version of web security configuration.

It was

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
```

It was fixed after I set it to

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
```